# How to branch the whole repository including ignore files

Tags: mercurial, branch, clone

I have a project, which is in the Mercurial repository. In the root folder there is a .hgignore file, which states, that the "Bin" folder should be ignored (and also some other files and folders).

Now I want to clone this repository but in a way, that ALL folders and files should be cloned, also the original ignored ones. If I just clone the repository, than I get only the files, which are included in the repository thus my bin folder is missing.

How can I get cloned repository with all files in it? I want to merge these two repositories together in a while...

PS - I am working on a legacy application which has a lot of external dll-s in the bin folder of the application. I know I should put them to a seperate folder, but that's another story.

Comment: Look, to be blunt. If you know you should put them into a separate folder, then **do it**. You don't need to move them, just copy them into a separate folder as well and commit that to the repository. This way, a full clone has everything you need. Yes, you would need to copy the files back into the Bin directory on a fresh clone, but that's heaps better than figuring out which files you're missing and from where to get them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just copy it.

Copy the whole tree from point a to point b, and the new copy will function perfectly as a repository. The only thing that would be different from a clone is the lack of hardlinks and that the default pull/push path will be set-up to be the same as the original, rather than pointing to the original. That's easy to change by editing `.hg/hgrc` if you want to.

Comment: @Martin: Yep, agreed. Hard-links are also lost.

Comment: Could there be any problems with merging those two repositories in the future?

Comment: @_simon_ Aside from from the repo-internal hard links and the `default` path a copy is the same thing as a clone. So merging code from a copied directory is exactly the same as merging code from a cloned directory.

Answer (score 2):

An ignored file is not in your repository, so it will not be cloned. You should copy these files by hand after you have cloned the repository.
When you copy those files, I think it won't be a problem if you overwrite other files that are in your repository (they're essentially the same files after all), so as long as you don't copy the .hg folder in the root of your checkout, you'll probably be fine.